# Extracting txt files from a jar

Tags: linux, bash, jar

I have a big home directory, under which there are many jar files. I need to aggregate the contents of all txt files, within the jar files in my home directory, into a single text file.

Can someone help me with this? I don't know how to write a script for this. I am using a Linux system.

To recap, I need to:

1. Find all jar files
2. Find all txt files within the jar files
3. Get the contents of these txt files into a single output file

Comment: I don't know what "write them into a common txt file" means.  But note that .jar files are just .zip files with some extra metadata conventions (and a few other differences like a formalized set of compression algorithms that you don't have to care about).  You can unpack them with a simple "unzip" and then operate over the file tree directly, which you might find simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we omit proper whitespace handling in file names, it boils down to:

```
searchdir='/home/username/'
outputtxt='/home/username/out.txt'

for jar in $(find "$searchdir" -iname '*.jar'); do
  for txt in $(unzip -l "$jar" | awk '/\.txt$/ {print $NF}'); do
    unzip -c "$jar" "$txt" | tail -n +3 >> "$outputtxt"
  done
done
```

You can also omit `| tail -n +3` from the inner most loop if you wish to include the unzip header in the output file. An example header:

```
Archive:  /home/username/filename.jar
  inflating: META-INF/maven/pom.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I would presumably use `jar` tool to do it-

```
for jarfile in `ls -1 *.jar`
do
    txtfiles=`jar tf "$jarfile"|grep ".txt"`   #find all txt files in the jar
    for files in $txtfiles
    do
      jar xf "$jarfile" $file     #extract just the txt file
      if [ $? -eq 0 ]             #check if extract was successful
      then
        cat "$file" >> aggregate_file.txt  
        rm -rf "$file"             #clean up the un-jar
      else
        print "Cannot extract $file from $jarfile..."
      fi
    done
done
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jar.html) is a descriptive on `jar`.